# Is this a vectorial space

Tags: vector-fields

I can't understand why the 0 vector here is not unique?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $(V,+,\cdot)$ is a vector space then $(V,+)$ is an **abelian** group. Can you give a counterexample to show that it isn't the case?

Answer (score 0):

$V$ is not a vector space because it does not respect the commutativity and associativity of addition.

There is an unique zero vector $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

We want a zero vector to satisfy $0+u=x+0=u$ for all vectors $u$.  However there is no such vector. Suppose $0=(a,b)$.  Then $0+(x,y)=(a+2x,b+3y)=(x,y)$.  But then $a+2x=x, b+3y=y$ for all $x,y$, which is impossible.